# PDOStatement::fetchAll() expects parameter 1 to be long, string given?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a basic database handler class where I have a public method that returns a result set using the `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` argument:

```
public function resultSet() {
    $this->execute();
    return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

However, I have determined that I need to use `PDO::FETCH_COLUMN` for a few usage cases, and so to maintain backwards compatibility, I added an optional parameter to my method:

```
public function resultSet($fetchType = "PDO::FETCH_ASSOC") {
    $this->execute();
    return $this->stmt->fetchAll($fetchType);
}
```

This results in an error instead of my expected return:

```
Warning: PDOStatement::fetchAll() expects parameter 1 to be long, string given
```

I understand that I am passing it a string, since I defined `$fetchType` as a string, but I don't know what `long` is at all, or how to define an optional parameter that contains my preferred fetch mode.

I decide to look at the documentation for [`PDO::fetchAll()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) and I only get more confused... the first data type it is expecting is an integer? (`int $fetch_type`).

So:

1. **How can I define an optional parameter which accepts a fetch type and passes it correctly?** and
2. **Why is the first accepted parameter of the data type integer?**

Comment: "expects parameter 1 to be long, **string** given." Try to find the only manually defined string in your code. It is not that hard.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I've already done that, if you'd just read the question: "...I understand that I am passing it a string, since I defined $fetchType as a string..."

Answer (score 3):

the warning explains it all, just change it to like:

```
public function resultSet($fetchType = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) {
    $this->execute();
    return $this->stmt->fetchAll($fetchType);
}
```